# CMSSignerDigestMismatchException: when trying to digitally sign document using deferred signature

Tags: java, itext, rsa, digital-signature

I am trying to digitially sign a PDF document using Digital signature using Java itext library.

Here are my implementation details:

1. I first retrieved the certificate chain with which to sign.

```java
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
        Certificate myCert = cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(Hex.decode(certHexStr)));
        Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[] { myCert };
```

2. Then I added empty signature field

```java
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
String fieldName = appearance.getFieldName();
document.setSigField(fieldName);
logger.info("Singnature fieldName: " + fieldName);
appearance.setCertificate(clientCertChain[0]);

if (document.getSignReq() != null) {
    SignRequest signReq = document.getSignReq();
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(signReq.getReason()))
        appearance.setReason(signReq.getReason());

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(signReq.getLocation()))
        appearance.setLocation(signReq.getLocation());
    int pageNumber = signReq.getPageNumber() == 0 ? 1 : signReq.getPageNumber();
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(signReq.getLeftX(), signReq.getLeftY(), signReq.getRightX(),
            signReq.getRightY());
    logger.info(rect.toString());
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(rect, pageNumber, fieldName);
```

3. Then I created the hash of the document

```java
// PrivateKeySignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA256",
// "SunMSCAPI");
String hashAlgorithm = "SHA256"; // "SHA-256"
BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
// saving the hash for using later
byte hash[] = DigestAlgorithms.digest(rg, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));

// logger.debug("pre-hash: " + Arrays.toString(hash));
String encodedhHash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);
document.setDigest(encodedhHash);
```

4. I then signed the digest using a remote client

```java
PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, certs, Constants.hashAlgorithm, null, bcDigest, false);
```

5. I then merged the signature

```java
byte[] signedEncoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(document.getSignedEncoded());
```

```java
logger.info("Signature fieldname: " + document.getSigField());
AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();

PdfDictionary v = af.getSignatureDictionary(document.getSigField());
if (v == null)
    throw new DocumentException("No field");
if (!af.signatureCoversWholeDocument(document.getSigField()))
    throw new DocumentException("Not the last signature");
PdfArray b = v.getAsArray(PdfName.BYTERANGE);
long[] gaps = b.asLongArray();
if (b.size() != 4 || gaps[0] != 0)
    throw new DocumentException("Single exclusion space supported");
RandomAccessSource readerSource = reader.getSafeFile().createSourceView();

int spaceAvailable = (int) (gaps[2] - gaps[1]) - 2;
if ((spaceAvailable & 1) != 0)
    throw new DocumentException("Gap is not a multiple of 2");
spaceAvailable /= 2;
if (spaceAvailable < signedContent.length)
    throw new DocumentException("Not enough space");
StreamUtil.CopyBytes(readerSource, 0, gaps[1] + 1, outs);
ByteBuffer bb = new ByteBuffer(spaceAvailable * 2);
for (byte bi : signedContent) {
    bb.appendHex(bi);
}
int remain = (spaceAvailable - signedContent.length) * 2;
for (int k = 0; k < remain; ++k) {
    bb.append((byte) 48);
}
bb.writeTo(outs);
StreamUtil.CopyBytes(readerSource, gaps[2] - 1, gaps[3] + 1, outs);
reader.close();
bb.close();
outs.close();
```

But when I try to verify the signature, it says,

```
CMSSignerDigestMismatchException: message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value - when trying to digitally sign document using deferred signature.
```

Also in pdf viewer, it says the pdf has been modified after signature

[image: Adobe reader]

I am using Java 11 with bouncycastle 1.70 and itext 7.0.4

Comment: First of all, if you _now_ try to implement signing with iText, I would propose you use a _current_ iText version. v7.0.4 is nearly 6 years old. The current v7 is 7.2.5, and since recently there even is a 8.0.0.

Comment: That been said, there are undefined variables and gaps in the code you show, so it's difficult to really analyze the issue. Please share enough of the relevant code (it is not relevant whether you set the reason field or not but it is relevant to see based on which data you create the CMS container, and how you create it). By the way, from the pieces you show I get the impression your signing approach is based on how one used to sign with iText versions before 5.3.x which was very easy to do wrong.

Comment: @mkl I changed itext version to 7.2.5 but received the same error.

Comment: @mkl Here is a minimum viable example: https://github.com/desertSniper87/Digital-Signing-Server. You may go through the `signDigestWeb` function in the https://github.com/desertSniper87/Digital-Signing-Server/blob/main/src/main/java/com/ca/signer/web/WebPdfSignerService.java

Comment: That's a lot of code, and at first glance it looks ok... Can you also share an example PDF signed by that service illustrating the issue? An analysis might help localizing the issue.

Comment: @mkl, I found out the issue. The remote signing server I was using was not padding the digest sent. Manually padding the the digest solved the issue. I added a answer. Thanks for the suggestions 

Comment: Great! Some signing services have the weirdest ideas... (To catch such details I had asked for an example PDF.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As evident in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2, the digest is to be padded with bytevalue (0x)30 31 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05 00 04 20 (we are using SHA256).

```java
        byte[] sha256bytes = new byte[] { 0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, (byte) 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03,
                0x04, 0x02, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20 };
        return ArrayUtils.addAll(sha256bytes, digest);
```

It should be the job of the remote signing server. But sending digest with the prefix fixed the issue.